# CrudRepository throwing data mismatch on user login

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to set up a user endpoint for my webapp. (/user/{id})
i have a thymeleaf login form that calls a getUser endpoint which scans the user database for user by email and password. once it finds the user, it redirects to /user/{id}. inside the request mapping for /user/{id} it uses the UsersService to call the UserRepository which calls findById(String string).

the value of the id is a long. the crud repository has a method findById(String string) and it should map it to a long since its defined in the wildcard as a  type. 
I'm feeding the method a string as it's telling me that its an incorrect data type.

how do i query for user by id? why is it throwing this incompatible type error?

```
// thymeleaf form with get to /user/getUser endpoint

<form action="#" method="GET" th:action="@{/user/getUser}" th:object="${loginRequestModel}">
<p>Email: <input th:field="*{email}" type="text"/></p>
<p>Password: <input th:field="*{password}" type="text"/></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" value="Reset"/></p>
</form>

// controller class with request mapping to /user 

   @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String userUploads(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        log.info("userUploads endpoint called<<");
        String returnValue;
        try {
            UserEntity userEntity = usersService.getUserById(id);

            returnValue = "this account belongs to: " +
                    userEntity.getFirstName() + userEntity.getLastName();

            log.info("returning new response entity<<");
            return returnValue;

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return "Couldn't load profile!";
        }


@GetMapping("/getUser")
public String getUser(@ModelAttribute LoginRequestModel loginRequestModel) {
        String userEmail = loginRequestModel.getEmail();
        UserEntity userEntity = usersService.getUserDetailsByEmail(userEmail);
        String id = String.valueOf(userEntity.getId());

        return "redirect:/user/" + id;

    }

// UsersService which contains the autowired CrudRepository

    @Override
    public UserEntity getUserDetailsByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }


    @Override
    public UserEntity getUserById(String userId) {
        return userRepository.findById(userId);
    }


// crud repository

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserEntity, Long> {

    UserEntity findByEmail(String email);
    UserEntity findByUsername(String username);
    UserEntity findById(String id);



}



// my user entity class

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "WEB_USERS")
@Data
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    public static final long serialVersionUID = -2056698267929616904L;

    protected UserEntity() {
    }

    public UserEntity(String email, String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    public String lastName;

    @Column(unique = true)
    public String email;

    @Column
    public String username;

    @Column
    public String password;

    @Override
    public String toString() {


        String toString =
                "\n\n\t > User Entity" +
                        "\n\n\t > Id:" + id +
                        "\n\n\t > First Name:" + firstName +
                        "\n\n\t > Last Name:" + lastName +
                        "\n\n\t > Email:" + email +
                        "\n\n\t > Username:" + username +
                        "\n\n\t > Password:" + password;

        return toString;




    }
}
```

the whole log relating to the query:

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - GET "/user/12", parameters={} 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to public java.lang.String tech.jdevmin.web.jdevminweb.io.LoginController.userUploads(java.lang.String) 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO  t.j.w.j.i.LoginController - userUploads endpoint called<< 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.q.c.i.CriteriaQueryImpl - Rendered criteria query -> select generatedAlias0 from UserEntity as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.id=:param0 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl - parse() - HQL: select generatedAlias0 from tech.jdevmin.web.jdevminweb.entity.UserEntity as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.id=:param0 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.ErrorTracker - throwQueryException() : no errors 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl - --- HQL AST ---
 \-[QUERY] Node: 'query'
    +-[SELECT_FROM] Node: 'SELECT_FROM'
    |  +-[FROM] Node: 'from'
    |  |  \-[RANGE] Node: 'RANGE'
    |  |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  |  |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'tech'
    |  |     |  |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'jdevmin'
    |  |     |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'web'
    |  |     |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'jdevminweb'
    |  |     |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'entity'
    |  |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'UserEntity'
    |  |     \-[ALIAS] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
    |  \-[SELECT] Node: 'select'
    |     \-[IDENT] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
    \-[WHERE] Node: 'where'
       \-[EQ] Node: '='
          +-[DOT] Node: '.'
          |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
          |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'id'
          \-[COLON] Node: ':'
             \-[IDENT] Node: 'param0'

[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.HqlSqlBaseWalker - select << begin [level=1, statement=select] 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.t.FromElement - FromClause{level=1} : tech.jdevmin.web.jdevminweb.entity.UserEntity (generatedAlias0) -> userentity0_ 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.t.FromReferenceNode - Resolved : generatedAlias0 -> userentity0_.id 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.t.FromReferenceNode - Resolved : generatedAlias0 -> userentity0_.id 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.t.DotNode - getDataType() : id -> org.hibernate.type.LongType@24d8f87a 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.t.FromReferenceNode - Resolved : generatedAlias0.id -> userentity0_.id 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.HqlSqlBaseWalker - select : finishing up [level=1, statement=select] 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.HqlSqlWalker - processQuery() :  ( SELECT ( {select clause} userentity0_.id ) ( FromClause{level=1} web_users userentity0_ ) ( where ( = ( userentity0_.id userentity0_.id id ) ? ) ) ) 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.u.JoinProcessor - Using FROM fragment [web_users userentity0_] 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.HqlSqlBaseWalker - select >> end [level=1, statement=select] 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl - --- SQL AST ---
 \-[SELECT] QueryNode: 'SELECT'  querySpaces (web_users)
    +-[SELECT_CLAUSE] SelectClause: '{select clause}'
    |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'userentity0_.id as id1_0_' {alias=generatedAlias0, className=tech.jdevmin.web.jdevminweb.entity.UserEntity, tableAlias=userentity0_}
    |  \-[SQL_TOKEN] SqlFragment: 'userentity0_.email as email2_0_, userentity0_.first_name as first_na3_0_, userentity0_.last_name as last_nam4_0_, userentity0_.password as password5_0_, userentity0_.username as username6_0_'
    +-[FROM] FromClause: 'from' FromClause{level=1, fromElementCounter=1, fromElements=1, fromElementByClassAlias=[generatedAlias0], fromElementByTableAlias=[userentity0_], fromElementsByPath=[], collectionJoinFromElementsByPath=[], impliedElements=[]}
    |  \-[FROM_FRAGMENT] FromElement: 'web_users userentity0_' FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=generatedAlias0,role=null,tableName=web_users,tableAlias=userentity0_,origin=null,columns={,className=tech.jdevmin.web.jdevminweb.entity.UserEntity}}
    \-[WHERE] SqlNode: 'where'
       \-[EQ] BinaryLogicOperatorNode: '='
          +-[DOT] DotNode: 'userentity0_.id' {propertyName=id,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=id,path=generatedAlias0.id,tableAlias=userentity0_,className=tech.jdevmin.web.jdevminweb.entity.UserEntity,classAlias=generatedAlias0}
          |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'userentity0_.id' {alias=generatedAlias0, className=tech.jdevmin.web.jdevminweb.entity.UserEntity, tableAlias=userentity0_}
          |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'id' {originalText=id}
          \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=param0, expectedType=org.hibernate.type.LongType@24d8f87a}

[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.ErrorTracker - throwQueryException() : no errors 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl - HQL: select generatedAlias0 from tech.jdevmin.web.jdevminweb.entity.UserEntity as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.id=:param0 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl - SQL: select userentity0_.id as id1_0_, userentity0_.email as email2_0_, userentity0_.first_name as first_na3_0_, userentity0_.last_name as last_nam4_0_, userentity0_.password as password5_0_, userentity0_.username as username6_0_ from web_users userentity0_ where userentity0_.id=? 
[http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.ErrorTracker - throwQueryException() : no errors 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [12] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [12] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:256)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.findById(Unknown Source)
    at tech.jdevmin.web.jdevminweb.service.UsersServiceImpl.getUserById(UsersServiceImpl.java:52)
    at tech.jdevmin.web.jdevminweb.io.LoginController.userUploads(LoginController.java:33)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [12] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.setParameter(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:385)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.setParameter(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$NamedOrIndexedQueryParameterSetter.lambda$setParameter$3(QueryParameterSetter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$ErrorHandling$1.execute(QueryParameterSetter.java:175)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryParameterSetter$NamedOrIndexedQueryParameterSetter.setParameter(QueryParameterSetter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.lambda$bind$0(ParameterBinder.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1085)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:96)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.invokeBinding(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:246)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.createQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:173)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:221)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 98 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the field `id` in your Entity class is type Long and the function in your controller in type String and also the parameter id in the function findUserById in UserService also type String too !

```
   @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String userUploads(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        // ...
    }
```

SOLUTION : modify your Pathvariable id in the Controller to Long. and modify the related function used with that controller too (ex : userService ...)

```
   @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String userUploads(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: But even on the official page this is what it tells you to do. I've followed tutorials where I've successfully done this exactly the same way. Is it okay to have an id as a string? Everywhere I've read says to use a Long and search by String value. I tried changing the crud repository to have <UserEntity, String> and it throws an error because the overridden method is this:     Optional<T> findById(ID var1);

Comment: @jjavaggdev Could I see your function in UserService?

Comment: [http-nio-8080-exec-3] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String] with root cause 
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String

Comment: thats after changing all to strings

Comment: @Override
    public UserEntity getUserById(String userId) {
        return userRepository.findById(userId);
    }

Comment: LOL, so your UserRepository interface should be extend Repository<EntityUser, String>, right?

Comment: like i said before, its supposed to be <User, Long>, it says so in all the guides, and when i switched it to string, it threw the error like i said before

Comment: so should i just have two id? one just to satisfy sql and another one to actually use in queries? because jpa won't let me assign a @Id to a String type

Comment: Reality if your Entity class primary key type is Long, you have to use that type along the way!

Comment: @jjavaggdev No, just one id is enough!

Comment: @jjavaggdev Just simplify follow like this: `[\n] public class EntityUser { @Id private Long id; //....} [\n] public class UserService { @Override public UserEntity getUserById(Long userId) { return userRepository.findById(userId); } } [\n] public interface UserRepository extends Repository<EntityUser, Long>{} `

Comment: if i change the CrudRepository to search by type long it forces me to change to this:     Optional<UserEntity> findById(Long id);

Comment: @jjavaggdev CrudRepository is included `Optional<UserEntity> findById(Long id)` by default, so in class `UserService` just write `@Override public UserEntity getUserById(Long userId) { return userRepository.findById(userId).get(); }`

Comment: that Optional<UserEntity> doesnt give me anything to work with. the only method i have available from it is .ifPresent()

Comment: No, in Optional class, there is a function  `public T get()` to get the object value in that Optional. ex : `userRepository.findById(userId); -> Optional<EntityUser>` and `userRepository.findById(userId).get(); -> EntityUser;`

Comment: Optional<UserEntity> userEntity = usersService.getUserById(id);

             UserEntity presentUserEntity = userEntity.ifPresent(userEntity1 -> userEntity1.toString());

Comment: i tried that^^ and it is saying reequired userEntity found void

Comment: try this : `Optional<UserEntity> userEntity = usersService.getUserById(id); UserEntity presentUserEntity = userEntity.get(); `

Comment: so you mean something like this could work?? UserEntity userEntity = usersService.getUserById(id).get();